# How to fix kafka streams problem related to group coordinator is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a problem when I try to run Kafka Streams application with PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG that equals to "exactly once semantic" for other cases as for example at least once semantic it works very well.

I noticed in the logs that something is going wrong and I found some of the recommendation here in order to fix this problem but unfortunately it didn't helped me :(

```
03:35:28.627 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=transform] Discovered group coordinator kafka:9093 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
03:35:28.627 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=transform] Group coordinator kafka:9093 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
03:35:28.628 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=to-transform] Discovered group coordinator kafka:9093 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
03:35:28.628 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=transform] Group coordinator kafka:9093 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
03:35:48.628 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=transform] Discovered group coordinator kafka:9093 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
03:35:48.630 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=transform] Found no committed offset for partition topic-0
03:35:48.631 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
03:35:48.631 INFO  o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to RUNNING
03:35:48.631 INFO  o.a.k.s.KafkaStreams - stream-client [transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697] State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING
03:35:48.632 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=transform] Attempt to heartbeat failed for since member id transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1-consumer-6aacbde6-4553-43ee-bc2f-2b5718e55acf is not valid.
03:35:48.632 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=transform] Found no committed offset for partition topic-0
03:35:48.633 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.SubscriptionState - [Consumer clientId=transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=transform] Resetting offset for partition topic-0 to offset 0.
03:35:48.634 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=transform] Giving away all assigned partitions as lost since generation has been reset,indicating that consumer is no longer part of the group
03:35:48.634 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=transform] Lost previously assigned partitions topic-0
03:35:48.634 INFO  o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [transform-f8268b2b-4673-49ac-9396-6a2b86d45697-StreamThread-1] at state RUNNING: partitions [topic-0] lost due to missed rebalance.
```

As for example first recommendation if I run just single kafka broker node then I have to set up partitions and replications configs to 1 as well second recommendation was to restart kafka broker that also gave no results

```
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.4.1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9093:9093"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper 
    links:
      - zookeeper:zk
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: OUTSIDE://kafka:9092,INSIDE://kafka:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: OUTSIDE://localhost:9092,INSIDE://kafka:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: 1
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 1048576
      KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES: 1048576
      KAFKA_GROUP_MAX_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: 30000
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 1
      KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_NUM_PARTITIONS: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_NUM_PARTITIONS: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_DELETE_RETENTION_MS: 86400000
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: topic:1:1, transform:1:1
```

Thanks for any help
kind regards, Victor

Answer (score 2):

There can be many reasons for the observed issue. In general, exaclty-once is more expensive and puts a higher load on the brokers and the KafkaStreams application.

Also note, that if you really want to get exactly-once processing, you should run with at least 3 brokers (and topics should be configured with a replication factor of 3, and min-isr of 2). Otherwise, EOS cannot really be guaranteed.

Increasing the `commit.interval.ms` might help to mitigate the issue. Note, that for EOS, it might lead to higher processing latency (that is the reason why the default commit interval is reduced to 100ms if EOS is enable). If you can accept a higher latency, you might want to increase it to for example 1 seconds.

Also, there is a heavy investment into EOS and newer versions contain many improvements. If you can, you might want to upgrade to upcoming 2.6 release and test the new "eos_beta" processing mode (requires brokers 2.5 or newer).